# Print the row only if the string does not exist in a specific column taking account each group of strings in other column by UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

So, I have the following tabulated file with thousand rows:

```
NP_000007.1     ACADM   1457    rs1061337       not_match
NP_000007.1     ACADM   2761    rs2229249       not_match
NP_000007.1     ACADM   2761    rs2229249       not_match
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1398
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1395
NP_000057.1     C8B     1078    rs1013579       117
NP_000057.1     C8B     932     rs856847        345
NP_000057.1     C8B     932     rs856831        not_match
NP_000057.1     C8B     932     rs856841        429
NP_000076.2     CLCNKB  48      rs5251          334
```

I would like to delete those rows for each group of strings grouped in first column if at least appears not_match pattern one time in fifth column. Thus, only the rows grouped by the same string in first column that corresponding to only numbers in fifth column are printed.

The desired output would be:

```
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1398
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1395
NP_000076.2     CLCNKB  48      rs5251          334
```

I think to do it in some steps separating the rows with "not_match" pattern and the numbers in fifth column and then see if there are coincidences in first column by a hash and discard these coincidences. However I would like to do in one step in the same file. How could I get it in Unix environment? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

a two pass algorithm will be the simplest

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {                       # in the first round 
         if($NF=="not_match") a[$1];   # record the keys to be deleted
         next}                         #
       !($1 in a)' file{,}             # in the second round skip them
```

note that `file{,}` is shorthand for `file file`

```
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1398
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1395
NP_000076.2     CLCNKB  48      rs5251          334
```

Comment: It works correctly @karakfa. Thanks! If I have understood correctly first do an array with first column when "not_match" pattern appears and then if any string in first column does not appear in the previous array print it, is it ok? I addition if I want to extract also the strings that have at least one "not_match" pattern all I have to do is remove "!"

Answer (score 1):

Alternative **`sort`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
sort -k1,1 -k5,5r file | awk '!($1 in a){ a[$1]=$5 }a[$1]!="not_match"'
```

The output:

```
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1398
NP_000019.2     AGL     1094    rs1042090       1395
NP_000076.2     CLCNKB  48      rs5251          334
```

Comment: works correctly too! Thanks @RomanPerekhrest. In fact the first column was already sorted but thanks again. I have understood the script I think